# Generate random integers with probabilities

Tags: javascript, random, probability

I'm a bit confused about how to generate integer values with probabilities.

As an example, I have four integers with their probability values: 1|0.4, 2|0.3, 3|0.2, 4|0.1

How can I generate these four numbers taking into account their probabilities?

Comment: If you want to know lots of technical details about how to do this quickly, this is a great resource.  For making a weighted choice among 4 choices, it's totally unneeded though. http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094873

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a useful trick :-)

```
function randomWithProbability() {
  var notRandomNumbers = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4];
  var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length);
  return notRandomNumbers[idx];
}
```

Comment: Correct direction, just create `notRandomNumbers` dynamically (given the numbers and their weight/probability) and it's ideal solution in my opinion.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. this looks just what I need.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: yes, I made it simple for clarity :-)

Comment: of course, I was just waiting for some more solutions to choose the best one ;)

Comment: Nope, I didn't change anything. I only now accepted your answer for it's more elegant solution than the other one.

Comment: Ah, I thought you accepted that one previously. Never mind. Yeah, my solution is more elegant :-)

Comment: I don't think this is an efficient way to do so. Let's assume we have probabilities such as: [0.000000000001, 0.299999999999, 0.7], so what will be the `notRandomNumbers` table in this case? Quiz: How much memory it will use? I would rather say that it is THE WORST possible solution to this problem.

Comment: @nosbor: yeah, the answer from bhups would perform better.

Answer (score 40):

A simple naive approach can be:

```
function getRandom(){
  var num=Math.random();
  if(num < 0.3) return 1;  //probability 0.3
  else if(num < 0.6) return 2; // probability 0.3
  else if(num < 0.9) return 3; //probability 0.3
  else return 4;  //probability 0.1
}
```

Comment: What if two numbers have the same probability? :-)

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev -> easy use the same differences between next steps

Answer (score 22):

More flexible solution based on @bhups answer. This uses the array of probability values (weights). The sum of 'weights' elements should equal 1.

```
var weights = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1]; // probabilities
var results = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // values to return

function getRandom () {
    var num = Math.random(),
        s = 0,
        lastIndex = weights.length - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < lastIndex; ++i) {
        s += weights[i];
        if (num < s) {
            return results[i];
        }
    }

    return results[lastIndex];
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use a continuous check of the probability and the rest of the random number.

This function sets first the return value to the last possible index and iterates until the rest of the random value is smaller than the actual probability.

The probabilities have to sum to one.

```js
function getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities) {
    var r = Math.random(),
        index = probabilities.length - 1;

    probabilities.some(function (probability, i) {
        if (r < probability) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
        r -= probability;
    });
    return index;
}

var i,
    probabilities = [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.09, 0.01 ],
    count = {},
    index;

probabilities.forEach(function (a) { count[a] = 0; });

for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    index = getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities);
    count[probabilities[index]]++
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution i find the most flexible, for picking within any set of object with probabilities:

```js
// set of object with probabilities:
const set = {1:0.4,2:0.3,3:0.2,4:0.1};

// get probabilities sum:
var sum = 0;
for(let j in set){
    sum += set[j];
}

// choose random integers:
console.log(pick_random());

function pick_random(){
    var pick = Math.random()*sum;
    for(let j in set){
        pick -= set[j];
        if(pick <= 0){
            return j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cases = {
  10 : 60,// 0-10 : 60  => 10%
  90 : 10,// 10-90 : 10  => 80%
  100 : 70,// 90-100 : 70 => 10%
};
function randomInt(){
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  for(let prob in cases){
    if(prob>=random){
      return cases[prob];
    }
  }
}
console.log(randomInt())
```

Answer (score 0):

Some variation on Rom098 answer to make it a bit more flexible. Added weights as array of unit instead.

```js
function randomWithProbability(outcomes, weights){
    if(!weights){
        weights=Array(outcomes.length).fill(1);
    }
    let totalWeight=weights.reduce((prev, curr)=>prev+=curr);
    const num=Math.random();
    let sum=0, lastIndex=weights.length-1;
    for(let i=0; i<=lastIndex; i++){
        sum+=weights[i]/totalWeight;
        if(num<sum) return outcomes[i];
    }
    return outcomes[lastIndex];
}

for(let i=0; i<20; i++){
  console.log(randomWithProbability([true, false], [10,1]));
}
```