# Genetic algorithm Selection

Tags: c#, genetic-algorithm

How to choose *n* best chromosomes and return them as an array?

```
Chromosome[] Selection(int n) {}
```

I know that I need to compare chromosomes by their fitness.
I have method `public double calculateFitness()`

Comment: can you provide calculateFitness() code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you have an array of `Chromosome`s you want to compare. Then you can simply order them by their fitness and take the best *n*:

```
Chromosome[] sourceArray = ..... // wherever you got them from
Chromosome[] bestN = sourceArray.
    OrderByDescending(chromosome => chromosome.calculateFitness()).
    Take(n).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at other non-elitist selection schemes to avoid [premature convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_convergence). In short, getting stuck in a local optima with no progress in terms of solutions' fitness quality. Alternative probabilistic schemes, rather easy to code, are Roulette-Wheel Selection or Tournament Selection.

Check out this other posts that may give you an idea about how to implement them:

- [Roulette-Wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298301/roulette-wheel-selection-algorithm)
- [Tournamet](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/tournament-selection-in-genetic-algorithms)