# Genetic algorithm - new generations getting worse

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, python-2.x, fitness, roulette-wheel-selection

I have implemented a simple Genetic Algorithm to generate short story based on Aesop fables. 
Here are the parameters I'm using:

**Mutation**: Single word swap mutation with tested rate with 0.01.

**Crossover**: Swap the story sentences at given point. rate - 0.7

**Selection**: Roulette wheel selection - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5315710/536474

**Fitness function**: 3 different function. highest score of each is 1.0. so total highest fitness score is 3.0.

**Population size**: Since I'm using 86 Aesop fables, I tested population size with 50.

**Initial population**: All 86 fable sentence orders are shuffled in order to make complete nonsense. And my goal is to generate something meaningful(at least at certain level) from these structure lost fables.

**Stop Condition**: 3000 generations.
And the results are below:

[image]

However, this still did not produce a favorable result. I was expecting the plot that goes up over the generations. Any ideas to why my GA performing worse result?

**Update**: As all of you suggested, I've employed elitism by 10% of current generation copied to next generation. Result still remains the same: 
[image]

Probably I should use tournament selection.

Comment: Why would you expect genetic algorithms to work on this problem? Are your choices of fitness functions and mutations/crossovers compatible?

Comment: The way I see story generation is it could be a search problem that simultaneously looks for the best content and structure of the document it is producing. And employing GA seem fit great for this task. What do you mean by compatible?

Comment: The way I see it, crossovers have an extremely low chance to make sense, and you may need an extraordinarily large population to avoid decreasing the maximum fitness by accumulations of harmful mutations/crossovers. It's far easier to write papers about how wonderful genetic algorithms would be if they were to work than to get them to work on nontrivial problems. Did you base your project on a past success of genetic algorithms, or someone's optimistic speculation?

Comment: If you have elitism and the fitness decreases then the elitism implementation is wrong. Elitism means copying **the best individuals** to the next generation **without a change**. Also check my edited answer, I added a possibly useful concept to think about :).

Answer (score 5):

All of the above responses are great and I'd look into them. I'll add my thoughts.

**Mutation**

Your mutation rate seems fine although with Genetic Algorithms mutation rate can cause a lot of issues if it's not right. I'd make sure you test a lot of other values to be sure.

With mutation I'd maybe use two types of mutation. One that replaces words with other from your dictionary, and one that swaps two words within a sentence. This would encourage diversifying the population as a whole, and shuffling words.

**Crossover**

I don't know exactly how you've implemented this but one-point crossover doesn't seem like it'll be that effective in this situation. I'd try to implement an n-point crossover, which will do a much better job of shuffling your sentences. Again, I'm not sure how it's implemented but just swapping may not be the best solution. For example, if a word is at the first point, is there ever any way for it to move to another position, or will it always be the first word if it's chosen by selection?

If word order is important for your chosen problem simple crossover may not be ideal.

**Selection**

Again, this seems fine but I'd make sure you test other options. In the past I've found rank based roulette selection to be a lot more successful.

**Fitness**

This is always the most important thing to consider in any genetic algorithm and with the complexity of problem you have I'd make doubly sure it works. Have you tested that it works with 'known' problems?

**Population Size**

Your value seems small but I have seen genetic algorithms work successfully with small populations. Again though, I'd experiment with much larger populations to see if your results are any better.

The most popular suggestion so far is to implement elitism and I'd definitely recommend it. It doesn't have to be much, even just the best couple of chromosome every generation (although as with everything else I'd try different values).

Another sometimes useful operator to implement is culling. Destroy a portion of your weakest chromosomes, or one that are similar to others (or both) and replace them with new chromosomes. This should help to stop your population going 'stale', which, from your graph looks like it might be happening. Mutation only does so much to diversify the population.

Comment: Mutation operator replaces random noun with random wordnet synonym word. Second mutation you mentioned is really dangerous. It might break the sentence grammar, structure and everything. My crossover operator is very simple: it just counts the number of sentences from the parent stories, and swap at half of it. Forex: dad story has 4 sentences and mom story has 6 sentences, the children stories will be dad.first2sentence+mom.last3sentence and vice versa. My fitness function is not perfect but i hope it can find a story heuristically that has a chance to be coherent.

Comment: I assumed that the randomly generated words had no grammar and structure and were completely random, with the genetic algorithm trying to find one with good grammar. If not, then this operator probably wouldn't work. If you could provide a bit more detail on the implementation and fitness function that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You may be losing the best combinations, you should keep the best of each generation without crossing(elite).  Also, your function seems to be quite stable, try other types of mutations, that should improve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think without crossover operator, it won't evolve that much. I was thinking if I should employ some elitism by allowing the top N% of solutions to be copied straight from one generation to the next. But not sure how much N% should be..

Comment: When I tryed genetic algorithm I found 15% as the best, is very experimental.  You should order the population by each fitness and choose 5% of the best in one fitness (and not just the best overall).  Maybe you can get the best of each one in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Drop 5% to 10% of your population to be elite, so that you don't lose the best you have.

Make sure your selection process is well set up, if bad candidates are passing through very often it'll ruin your evolution. 
You might also be stuck in a local optimum, you might need to introduce other stuff into your genome, otherwise you wont move far.

Moving sentences and words around will not probably get you very far, introducing new sentences or words might be interesting.

If you think of story as a point x,y and your evaluation function as f(x,y), and you're trying to find the max for f(x,y), but your mutation and cross-over are limited to x -> y, y ->y, it makes sense that you wont move far. Granted, in your problem there is a lot more variables, but without introducing something new, I don't think you can avoid locality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to leave elitism as you suggested. What do you think about the initial population? from 86 i start with 50. I suspect this might be another reason.

Comment: There is no issue that I know of for changing the population size after it's been created, unless you don't have much to begin with. Otherwize, more is better up to the point that it becomes too expensive, so it depends on how expensive your bottleneck is (probably your Fitness evaluation). tl;dr: the more the population the longer it takes to go through a generation, so just find a good balance between the two!

Answer (score 3):

As @GettnDer said, elitism might help a lot.

What I would suggest is to use different selection strategy. The roulette wheel selection has one big problem: imagine that the best indidivual's fitness is e.g. 90% of the sum of all fitnesses. Then the roulette wheel is not likely to select the other individuals (see e.g. [here](http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/genetic-algorithms/selection.php)). The selction strategy I like the most is the [tournament selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_selection). It is much more robust to big differences in fitness values and the selection pressure can be controlled very easily.

**Novelty Search**

I would also give a try to [Novelty Search](http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/noveltysearch/userspage/). It's relatively new approach in evolutionary computation, where you don't do the selection based on the actual fitness but rather based on *novelty* which is supposed to be some metric of how an individual is different in its behaviour from the others (but you still compute the fitness to catch the good ones). Of special interest might be combinations of classical fitness-driven algorithms and novelty-driven ones, like the [this one](http://pages.isir.upmc.fr/evorob_db/moin.wsgi/NoveltyBasedMultiobjectivization?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mouret_2009.pdf) by J.-B. Mouret.

Answer (score 2):

When working with genetic algorithms, it is a good practice to structure you chromosome in order to reflect the actual knowledge on the process under optimization.

In your case, since you intend to generate stories, which are made of sentences, it could improve your results if you transformed your chromosomes into structured phrases, line `<adjectives>* <subject> <verb> <object>* <adverbs>*` (huge simplification here).

Each word could then be assigned a class. For instance, Fox=subject , looks=verb , grapes=object and then your crossover operator would exchange elements from the same category between chromosomes. Besides, your mutation operator could only insert new elements of a proper category (for instance, an adjective before the subject) or replace a word for a random word in the same category.

This way you would minimize the number of nonsensical chromosomes (like *Fox beautiful grape day sky*) and improve the discourse generation power for your GA.

Besides, I agree with all previous comments: if you are using elitism and the best performance decreases, then you are implementing it wrong (notice that in a pathological situation it may remain constant for a long period of time).

I hope it helps.